# ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php, function, pdo

I have a fuction in php class:

```
public function details($id) {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM khoa WHERE ma_khoa = :ma";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindparam(":ma", $ma);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetch();
            return $result; 
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

then, I use this function in form:

```
<form method="POST" action="update_post.php"> 
    <div class="row100">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="inputBox">
                <input type="text">
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $kh['ma_khoa']; ?>" name="makhoa">
                <span class="text">Mã khoa</span>
                <span class="line"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

With `$kh = $khoa->details($id);` and $khoa is variable to connect to database.

But i get this notice:

[image]

Can you explain for me about this error and the way to solved this?

Comment: Do you always use **bindparam()** with PDO? Because I know of `bindParam()`

Comment: Seems you wrote `$ma` instead of `$id` too... Check that one too

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, i saw it.

Comment: You're welcome. Then I guess I have to delete my answer then

Answer (score 0):

As your log said, your call `$kh = $khoa->details($id);` had `$kh = false`
So please recheck and debug your details function.

And of course, **false is a bool value**, cannot be access with as an array.